# Favicon Content-Type: text/plain - "AddType image/ico .ico" doesn't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, optimization, http-headers

I asked my developer to to set an expire date for the favicon by adding to the .htaccess file the following line:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresByType image/ico "access plus 1 years"
```

But it didn't have an expire date, couldn't figure it out till I loaded the icon in Firefox and noticed this part of the response headers

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=WINDOWS-1251
```

I was then advised to add the following: (to get Apache to set the correct mime type for the favicon)

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
AddType image/ico .ico
</IfModule>
```

But it didn't do the trick, not sure why, can there be any conflict that overrides the mod_mime.c? or any other reason?

Please advise

Thanks

Added: I currently have this to set expire date:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 years"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 years"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 years"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 years"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 years"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 years"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 years"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 years"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Did you set `ExpiresActive On` in your .htaccess file before `ExpiresByType`?

Comment: the expire is not the issue here since it works fine for all file types but the icon

Comment: Is `mod_mime` installed? In any case, you may want to consider a more aggressive expiration. Yahoo uses 10 years, which is what Steve Sauders recommends.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try adding the following to your .htaccess file instead.

```
<IfModule mod_header.c>

  <FilesMatch "\.ico$">
    # cache .ico files for 1 year(31536000 sec)
    Header set Cache-control max-age=31536000
  </FilesMatch>

</IfModule>
```

**EDIT:**

Note, that you have

> AddType image/**ico** .ico

bur you are using

> ExpiresByType image/**x-icon** "access plus 1 years"

which could also be the issue. To resolve, you could change to

> AddType image/**x-icon** .ico

Comment: Thanks first:) @Ulrich
see my added above, do I need to change anything or just add your few lines? does it make any difference the order the lines are entered?

Comment: add my lines after yours i.e. after the closing **mod_expires.c** `</IfModule>`

Comment: AddType image/x-icon .ico didn't help, didn't try other solution yet, whats interesting here is that when I add the <IfModule mod_mime.c> in a .htaccess of a subfolder it does work (don't want to work with htaccess on subfolders though, would rather try to get to the cause of the problem)